# How do I get inputStream to read BEFORE outputStream is handled?

Tags: java, c, multithreading, inputstream, outputstream

I have a simple **c program** that is basically:

```
printf("name?\n");
char name[20];
scanf("%s", name);
printf("hi %s\n", name);
```

And a **Java program** that attempts to be a middle-man.

So the Java program **should** do this:

1 - prints "name?"

2 - user types "Tea"

3 - prints "hi Tea"

But **instead** does this:

1 - prints nothing

2 - user types "Tea"

3 - prints "name?\n hi Tea"

The java program runs the c program with:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c program");
```

and each thread involves a version of:

```
myProcess.getInputStream();
```

I know the java program can read everything from the c program, and can pass user inputs and get feedback; but I don't know why the **inputStream** waits for the **outputStream** when they are running concurrently.

Comment: Have a look at `man 3 fflush` and use it in your C program after your first print statement.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I am a bit confused by it. I have tried fflush(stdin) after the first print in c, as well as any other place I can think to flush. I am not sure what you mean by "man 3 fflush" though and didn't get many results from searching that phrase.

Comment: (comment too long, so pt2:)

The only thing I can think of is that the InputStream is reading the OutputStream as some kind of object and doesn't finish until that object has converted into a string. I'm not sure how the current while() statement could check for that object as it currently checks the input (int) != -1. But I'm not sure that is the problem as the first call of input.available() returns 0, so it's like c refuses to hand over anything until the scanf() has been resolved

Comment: `printf` writes to `stdout` which is why you need to write `fflush(stdout)`. With `man 3 fflush` I suggested you should read the man-page of the `fflush` function.